# Collection view's last focused index path lost after reload data in tvOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, tvos

In my tvOS app, I have a collection view where I've set its `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` to `true`. As this is not enough to get this behaviour, I've also overridden a method in my `UIViewController` like this:

```
override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    return collectionView
}
```

This was working fine until I started reloading the collection view for some reasons. It does work if, being the collection view visible, I call `collectionView.reloadData()`.

This doesn't work, tho, if I do the reload when the collection view is not visible, for example, when I'm in a detail view after tapping one of the items. When I come back to the grid, the focused index path is not the one I tapped.

As a workaround, I'm managing this non-ideal scenario:

1. As the reload is triggered by fresh data coming from my backend, I only call `collectionView.reloadData()` when the collection view is visible (because I know that the last focused index doesn't change here).
2. I call `collectionView.reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)` to have the latest content available when the user comes back.

How can I do this properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you hold the last index path in another variable (ie an int) that you control? Are there delegate methods you could use to update the variable?

Answer (score 3):

Recently I got this issue also, my situation is pretty much same to you.

I also called `collectionView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`

**And then**

I changed from

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

to

```
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems())
```

It works for me most of time, there is still approximately <5% chance to mess up the last focus index

Comment: Hi, Breek. Nice one, have to try it myself. What I finally did was to reload the collection view in viewDidAppear and then, when I receive new data (periodically) or when the app becomes active, I reload the collection view only if the view controller is visible. It's horrible stuff but seems to work so far.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` to `false`, and implement `indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView:` to achieve the same behavior.

Comment: Interesting. Here I should hold somehow the index path of the focused view, right?

Comment: Yes, use a property to hold the currently focused index path and update it in collectionView:didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator: